# How to Resolve the java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError for com/google/common/io/ByteStreams in Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

hi I have downloaded the selenium and added it in libraries but when I run this code

```
package Selenium;

import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class learning {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\benis\\Desktop\\eclipse\\chromedriver-win64\\chromedriver-win64\\chromedriver.exe");
        
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        
        driver.get("https://www.facebook.com");
    }
}
```

it showS me this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/io/ByteStreams
> at org.seleniumhq.selenium.remote_driver/org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.parseLogOutput(DriverService.java:472)
> at org.seleniumhq.selenium.chrome_driver/org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.loadSystemProperties(ChromeDriverService.java:257)
> at org.seleniumhq.selenium.remote_driver/org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:495)
> at org.seleniumhq.selenium.chrome_driver/org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:137)
> at org.seleniumhq.selenium.chrome_driver/org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:51)
> at SeleniumTraining/Selenium.learning.main(learning.java:11)
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.io.ByteStreams
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
> ... 6 more

Can anyone help I really don't know what to do I'm just trying to learn selenium btw the version of selenium is 4.13.0 and the chromedriver is 117.0.5938.150 Thank you.